# DalvikVM with Input

Tags: android, dalvik

How can I start with dalvikvm  an .jar-file with an input. Something like that:

```
dalvikvm -cp /path to jar/test.jar "hello"
```

The main method of the test.jar will be just print this hello to console. It something like that possible? What is the right way to give this input to the main method, for example as an input for String [] args of the main method.

Comment: This isn't really a supported path for programming for Android. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you followed [these](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/04/command-line-java-on-dalvikvm/) steps? It looks like you need to run something like this:

> # /system/bin/dalvikvm -Xbootclasspath:/system/framework/core.jar -classpath /data/CmdLine.jar org.apache.HelloWorld
>   /system/bin/dalvikvm -Xbootclasspath:/system/framework/core.jar -classpath /data/CmdLine.jar org.apache.HelloWorld
>
> Hello World!

Comment: Yes.  I can run an Hello World class. But I want to run .jar with an input from terminal.

Comment: I would assume that any additional parameters would be passed to your main method just like regular java. What have you tried?

Comment: `dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/download/test.jar com.test.Test "hello" ` and my Test.java has main method.

Comment: So the first element in your String[] args array should be `"hello"`

Comment: yes! and in test.jar i make just System.out.println of this `Hello` but it doesnt work

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is then. It sounds like it's working to me. Could you post your code?

Comment: oh, I found my problem, I should take args[0] and not args[1]. Now it works..thanks)))

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar:
/system/bin/dalvikvm -Xbootclasspath:/system/framework/core.jar **-Xverify:none** **-Dosgi.debug=file:/data/.option**s .........**-Dosgi.parentClassloader=ext** -classpath ..... -console -clean

Instead of passing parameters through String[],I do not know how to do in this case, you could use the -D"nameparameter"="value" format (see adb shell dalvikvm -help) that allows you to define also new parameters (I used only predefined ones) and send them to the vm; then in your main class you could get them using String prop=System.getProperty("nameparameter")