# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal

Tags: java, android

Here is my simple test program

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.net.LocalSocket;
import android.net.LocalSocketAddress;

public class TestAndroid
{
    public TestAndroid() {
        super();
    }

    private void run() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("started");

        LocalSocket ls = new LocalSocket();

        System.out.println("connecting");
        ls.connect(new LocalSocketAddress("blablabla"));
        System.out.println("connected");
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) 
    {
        try {
            new TestAndroid().run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I use Oracle jdk 1.6.0, this is a build commands

```
javac -cp $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platforms/android-9/android.jar TestAndroid.java
dx --dex --output=test.dex TestAndroid.class
```

This command runs test application in colsole on Android

```
dalvikvm -cp test.dex TestAndroid
started
connecting
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal:(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:287)
    at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:130)
    at TestAndroid.run(TestAndroid.java:17)
    at TestAndroid.main(TestAndroid.java:24)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What wrong with my code? I think android.net.LocalSocket is available on any android system.

Comment: Possible duplicate? Not sure enough to cast a close vote... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885269/dalvikvm-with-input

Answer (score 0):

This example will not work. It must be standard project of android application with manifest. This code works as explected if it was places into such project.